# how to express taxonomy-like relationships with a relational diagram

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I'm trying to represent a simple classification scheme via a relational database. Or more specifically I'm trying to figure out if it's a good idea or not.

When I look at an image such as this http://www.talkstandards.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/taxonomy-of-standards.jpg, that I just picked off google, I see a bunch of one-to-many associations. that this happens to be amphibians is purely coincidental as I'm not a biologist.

I'm pretty new at databases and just wondering if there is a good way of dealing with a hierarchical taxonomy like schema

Comment: Lots of good articles out there on hierarchical data

Comment: i see. here is a great article http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Yep, that's a classic. Google's the best.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example : same table case
Make a column to forein key parent and a column for the level
At top level node is 1 and parent is null;